# Best way to return count of nested objects without list them

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to count a list of nested objects, but don't want to return the nested objects.

I have the classes:

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int ID {get; set}
    public List<Produto> produto {get; set;}
    public int produtoCount {get; set;}
}

public class Produto
{
    public ID {get; set}
    public string data {get; set;}
}
```

I have tried using produtoCount in Categoria class, but it only has value when I use a Include of Produto class, like this:

```
(new Categoria()).AsQueryable().Include(p => p.Produto).ToList();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

```
DbContext.Categorias
  .Where(c => c.Id == id)
  .Select(c => new    
  { 
    // Assuming you also want the Categoria
    Categoria = c,
    ProdutoCount = c.produto.Count()
  })
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. It may help you.

```
public class Categoria
{
    public int ID {get; set}
    private List<Produto> produto {get; set;}
    public int produtoCount {get {return produto.Count();} }
}

public class Produto
{
    public ID {get; set}
    public string data {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks,
Amit Prajapati

Comment: This would not solve the `but don't want to return the nested objects. ` as the OP stated.